# Multi-page table over two columns

Tags: tables, two-column

I can create tables over both columns in two-column mode using table* with tabular and multi-page tables using longtable or supertabular but I am not able to combine both.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular*}{\linewidth}{llllll}
column1 &column2    &column3    &column4    &column5    &column6\\                                                                                                                            
\end{supertabular*}
\end{document}
```

- longtable does not work in two-column mode at all ("longtable not in 1-column mode")
- supertabular* compiles (using `\begin{supertabular*}{\linewidth}{...}`, as recommended in another Question) but keeps to use one column anyways and overlaps if that space is not sufficient (see MWE above)

Comment: Perhaps switching to one column, using longtable/supertabular, and then switching to two columns again? Package multicol allows you to change the number of columns in the middle of the document.

Comment: P.S.: When having a caption at the top, latex creates a full page for the caption only and starts the table itself only on the next page. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `supertabular` package, which is known to have certain weaknesses, I suggest you use the [xtab](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xtab) pacakge and its `xtabular` and `xtabular*` environments.

I gather you want the long table is also quite wide and thus needs to span both columns. To obtain this behavior, you need to issue the instruction `\onecolumn` *before* `\begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}...}`, and you need to issue the instruction `\twocolumn` *after* `\end{xtabular*}`. In order to avoid getting a wretched-looking mid-page page break when LaTeX encounters the `\onecolumn` directive, I suggest you also load the `afterpage` package and encase the entire `xtabular*`-related stuff in an `\afterpage{...}` instruction. For instance:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xtab,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]  % filler text

--- here's the call to start an xtabular* environment. 
Execution is deferred until the start of the next page ---

\afterpage{\onecolumn
\begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll}
\hline
column1 &column2    &column3    &column4    &column5    &column6\\
%....
column1 &column2    &column3    &column4    &column5    &column6\\
\hline
\end{xtabular*}
\twocolumn
} % end of scope of "\afterpage" directive

\lipsum[6-10] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Depending on the length of the table, there may still be some empty space at the bottom of the last page of the table; however, that's usually much less severe a problem than having a bad page immediately before the start of the table.

Comment: Thanks, this works great so far! But how do I add caption and label? When I put it in a table, it doesn't span multiple pages anymore.

Comment: @KonradHöffner - For sure, *do not place an `xtabular` environment inside a `table` environment*. Please consult the user guide of the `xtab` package on how to use macros such as `\topcaption`, `\tablefirsthead`, etc.