# How can I split a table over two columns?

Tags: tables, longtabu, supertabular

Apologies if this has already been asked, but I can't seem to find an answer to my exact query.

I am working on a two column document using the book document class.
I am using the tabular environment to create a table, however I've noticed that LaTeX is not willing to split the table over two columns.

I don't wish to break the table by ending the tabular environment and starting a new one (as suggested by one post of here), as the document is a work in progress, and I would prefer LaTeX to automatically break the tables as it sees fit.

Would the supertabular environment help with this? I have also read about longtable and longtabu, and are now trying to work out which is best suited.

The tables don't have headers or captions, and are all the same width.

I am still getting to grips with LaTeX after a break of 20 years, so any help is appreciated.

I have tried the longtable option but gives an error of 'not in 1-column mode'.

Comment: Have you had a look at the answers to these questions? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161431/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256465/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23488/134144. From these answers, the packages `supertabular` or its extended version `xtab` seem to be a good choice.

Comment: longtable is not intended for this (your edit does not make sense).