# Long table that spans two columns using xtab

Tags: xtab

I want a page-wide table in my document, which is two column - but the table is also going to be longer than one page.

I tried longtable initially but I later learned that longtable doesn't work in a two column document.

I found a similar answer and solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256465/multi-page-table-over-two-columns), which gives an example of how to do this using the xtab package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xtab,afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]  % filler text

--- here's the call to start an xtabular* environment. 
Execution is deferred until the start of the next page ---

\afterpage{\onecolumn
\begin{xtabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll}
\hline
column1 &column2    &column3    &column4    &column5    &column6\\
%....
column1 &column2    &column3    &column4    &column5    &column6\\
\hline
\end{xtabular*}
\twocolumn
} % end of scope of "\afterpage" directive

\lipsum[6-10] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

I can get this example working okay. But instead of using:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

I need to use:

```
\documentclass{emulateapj}
```

When I do this, I get the following error message:

```
l.74   \noalign{\global\let\\=\@savcr}}}
```

All I want is a page-wide table that can span the two columns of the [emulateapj class](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~alexey/emulateapj/emulateapj.cls) and be longer than one page.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

First, `emulateapj` defines `\tablehead`, which is also defined in `xtabs` and generates an error.

Second, `emulateapj` uses `revtex4-1.cls` internally, which undefines `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn`. Instead it uses `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid`.

You said that you tried `longtable`, and it doesn't work in a two column mode. However, it seems to work OK if we change to one column before and then back to two column afterwards.

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{emulateapj}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-9]

\onecolumngrid
\begin{longtable}{llllll}
  \tablecaption{A long table}
  \tablehead{column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6}
  column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6 \\
  column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6 \\
  column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6 \\
  column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6 \\
  column1 & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5 & column6 \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}
\twocolumngrid

\lipsum[10-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]